# How to solve html form submission with input containing "select from" keywords?

Tags: html, forms, internal-server-error

This issue is being represented only on server-side and not localhost.

When submitting a simple form with one textarea containing the two keywords "select" and "from" in this order, or even separated with multiple words; the form submission is showing the following error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

This error has been generated even with the following sentence: "The selection of this team will be from the list ...", since "selection" contains the word "select" in it and followed by "from" keyword.

The only temporary solution is to use "select" or "from" capitalized to prevent the internal server error. However, this is not what I need. I need to solve it with a reasonable solution.

Comment: Can you show us your `HTML` or `PHP` code

Comment: @NebojsaNebojsa This the html code that I used:

<form action="test.php" method="POST">
 <textarea name="text" class="form-control textarea-tinymce" placeholder="insert"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually caused by the firewall of your server. To solve it you need to check the error log file and see what is the error provided, then you will have to add an exception for this error.
If you find it hard to be done, you can contact the support of your server and they can do it for you. Hope this can help.

Comment: I have been talking to the support and they just added an exception for this error. This is a security feature added to the server to prevent sql injections. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is on server side it may depend on the method you use to submit form data.

First, please carefully check documentation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

> The GET Method
>
> GET is used to request data from a specified resource.
>
> The POST Method
>
> POST is used to send data to a server to create/update a resource.
>
> The PUT Method
>
> PUT is used to send data to a server to create/update a resource.

Comment: This not what I am asking about, I did try different methods and nothing changed. The html code that I used is the following:

<form action="test.php" method="POST">
 <textarea name="text" class="form-control textarea-tinymce" placeholder="insert"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>

Comment: I tried your code - it works on my machine. So, it's a server-side error, meaning the problem probably isn't with your computer or internet connection but instead with the website's server. Try to run your code in different environment, clear cookies, browsing data, etc.